# Getting object type from datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, object, datagrid

Is there a way to get the object type from a datagrid ? I've got a dynamic data grid which displays female and male staff (both different objects)

Thanks

Rolls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want data type for selected row then you can do following:

```
datagrid.SelectedItem.GetType()
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing a code example, any answer is going to be a bit of a guess, but here goes.

Can you not subclass your staff as follows and allow access to a property, Gender, on the base?

```
public enum Gender 
{ 
    Male, Female
}

public class Staff 
{ 
    public Staff(Gender gender)
    {
        this.Gender = gender;
    }
    public Gender Gender { get; private set; }
} 

public class FemaleStaff : Staff
{ 
    public FemaleStaff() : base(Gender.Female)
    {
    }
}

public class MaleStaff : Staff
{ 
    public MaleStaff () : base(Gender.Male)
    {
    }
}
```

This way any object you get out of the datagrid of type Staff can be interrogated using the Gender property to find its derived type, then cast appropriately.